# I need tag for format string by regex

Tags: django, django-templates

In my database I have a MacAddress field which is a simple string such as `1234567890AB`.  In my template I need to render this field to something like `12:34:56:78:90:AB`.

I have tried to use the 'join' tag, but can't find any solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [**custom template tag**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this

```
def split_len(seq, length):
    return ":".join([seq[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)])

split_len("1234567890AB", 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just start write my own after googling